# Error running bundle install on rails os x 10.7.4 xcode 4.3.2 rvm 1.14.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, databasedotcom-gem

Trying to get a new rails app up and I can't start the server without bundle installing.  I get this error.  I tried other stacks with no avail.  Thanks in advance for any guidance!

```
Using coffee-rails (3.1.1) 
Using columnize (0.3.6) 
Using country_select (0.0.2) 
Using daemon_controller (1.0.0) 
Using database_cleaner (0.7.2) 
Using multipart-post (1.1.5) 
Using databasedotcom (1.3.0) 
Using debugger-ruby_core_source (1.1.2) 
Installing debugger-linecache (1.1.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
extconf.rb:2:in `require': no such file to load -- debugger/ruby_core_source (LoadError)
    from extconf.rb:2


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/jahrichie/.bundler/tmp/2264/gems/debugger-linecache-1.1.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/jahrichie/.bundler/tmp/2264/gems/debugger-linecache-1.1.1/ext/trace_nums/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing debugger-linecache (1.1.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install debugger-linecache -v '1.1.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you have missed to use a ruby or install bundler in the used ruby and bundler was installed in system ruby (but was rather not the case), try:

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --install
```

It will make sure you use a ruby and that it is installed.

Comment: My rvm install is wacko. Requires me to run rvm use system every time I run a new shell. But that solved my issue, hopefully isolated to my ghetto environment.